# Cannot manage maven profiles in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Maven project with a pom.xml with some profiles like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>staging</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.base.url>https://staging.url.de/</webdriver.base.url>
            <server.id>staging</server.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>rc</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.base.url>https://rc.url.de/</webdriver.base.url>
            <server.id>rc</server.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.base.url>https://www.url.de/</webdriver.base.url>
            <server.id>prod</server.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

as you can see, in the `staging` profile I have:

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

and if I move this code block to another profile(let's say `rc`) nothing changes - will be used `staging`. I have tried even delete `staging` profile and it executes anyway. Just don't get how to fix it. How to make it possible to execute different profiles, like it was before?

PS this project was working perfect for a long time. But today profiles got crazy.

Comment: File --> Invalidate Caches and restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since working on IntelliJ, Please do this.

```
File --> Invalidate Caches and restart
```

Happy Coding!!